# Youtube JS API cuePlaylist Filtering

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to add ordering to the search query for the Youtube JS API but I cannot get it to work.

This is a standard search using browser

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test
```

This is part of the script that does the same search but using the player

```
player.cuePlaylist({listType:'search', list:'test'});
```

Tested it and it works perfectly. However when I want to add ordering to the search query. It doesn't work.

For example, the searching for test with extra filter "Today". IT doesn't work (play list is empty array).

The browser search is

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=CAESAggC&q=test
```

This however

```
player.cuePlaylist({listType:'search', list:'sp=CAESAggC&q=test'});
```

Does not yield a result. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#cuePlaylist) states:

```
If the listType property value is search, then the list property specifies the search query.
```

I tried replacing & with & a m p ;(without spaces) but still no dice.

I also couldn't find anything related to filtering in the documentation.

Basically the question is how do I apply filtering to the cuePlaylist method.

Edit:

Tried this:

```
 player.cuePlaylist({listType:'search', list:'test', sp:'CAESAggC'});
```

The sp didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if cuePlaylist supports filtering but, the closest I can suggest is to use a search function

```
type: 'GET',
data: {
key: 'API_KEY',
q: query,
part: 'snippet'
}
})
```

then add a order by or any filters you can add, you can check [Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) document for additional info.

Here is a snippet for it :

```
// search video
$("#search").click(function() {
var query = $("#query").attr("value");
if ( !query ) {
return;
}
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
data: {
key: 'AIzaSyBda8mhaE8x10RiF0uzvBMPUszbUIQsy0g',
q: query,
part: 'snippet'
}
}).done(function(data) {
player.stopVideo();
player.clearVideo();
$('#video').fadeIn();
var videos = [];
console.log(data);
$.each(data.items, function() {
console.log(this.id.videoId)
videos.push(this.id.videoId);
});
// sort by favorite
videos = videos.sort(function(a, b) {
return b.favoriteCount - a.favoriteCount;
});
player.cuePlaylist(videos);
});
});
});
```

Here is the source for the [snippet](https://github.com/koba04/YouTube-Continuous-Player/blob/master/iframe_api_cue_playlist.html), I made some adjustment using the [tutorial](http://www.w3tweaks.com/web-api/21-youtube/45-search-youtube-videos-using-youtube-v3-api-using-jquery-ajax-call.html) because the github is using api v2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks, you need to add order and it would work. For example latest uploaded videos first, order: 'date'. The video sorting is not needed (for me anyway). Also videos contains ids not sure for what you mean favoriteCount since it contains strings.